# How to call a web server running locally from remote server

Tags: node.js, proxy, local

I have a remote website written in Node. I have a separate website that I'm running on my local machine. I'd like to try and figure out what I need to do to allow the remote website to call my local site. So, for example:

1. Remote app at http://example.com
2. Local app at localhost:3000. My IP address is 123.45.678.
3. I run some script on my local machine that gives the remote app access to the local app.
4. Remote app can ping 123.45.678:8081/users (just an example) and receives the response from localhost:3000/users.

Is this possible? Ideally this is a script that could be written in node and run on the local machine to give the remote server access. Manually configuring my router is not an option, as I want other people to be able to easily run this script and give the remote app access to their local app. If anybody could point me in the right direction I'd appreciate it.

Edit:

This guy is doing pretty much exactly what I describe, so it is possible. I'm not entirely sure how he's doing it though - only the client code is open source: https://github.com/proxylocal/proxylocal-gem

Comment: Other than step 4 which, as written, indicates port remapping, this would all be feasible. Your users would probably have to do something with their routers just to open up inbound access and set up port forwarding to the specific machine behind their router anyway, so if manual router configuration is out of the question, you probably need to think about a different approach. Maybe I am misunderstanding your goal however.

Answer (score 0):

if you have private white ip address - i mean, you computer is accessible from internet, you can do it.

If somebody can open the url of your IP, this is possible

> I want other people to be able to easily run this script and give the remote app access to their local app.

i think this is not possible without tunning router and having separate ip address.
You can extract the IP address from request in nodejs - `request.ip`, and probably it is whitelisted private address